# Definition of countable dimension of vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, definition, locally-convex-spaces, metrizability

It's a well known that Hausdorff locally convex space $(X, P)$, where $P$ is a family of seminorms which generate topology on $X$ is metrizable iff $P$ is equivalent to an at most countable subfamily $P_0 \subset P$. Using this i am trying to prove that the weak topology on $X$ generated by $Y$ where $(X,Y)$ is a dual pair ($=$dual system) is metrizable iff the dimension of $Y$ is at most countable, so here comes my problem, in which sense we understand **the dimension of Y is at most countable?** Is it about Hamel basis, or about Schauder basis, or in another way, because the are several ways to define a dimension of vector space?

Comment: Well, space $V$ has dimension $n$ if there is a set of $n$ independent vectors that generate $V$. The same can be said for infinite dimension: A vector space $V$ has countable dimension if there is a countable set $S$ of independent vectors (none of these vectors is a finite linear combination of the others) such that every $v\in V$ is a finite linear combination of the vectors in $S$

Answer (score -1):

The metrisability is due to the countable local base such a space needs to have.

Countable dimension is just a linear property: a countable set of vectors that (finitely) generates the space, so a countable Hamel basis. There are many metrisable locally convex spaces that are not countable dimensional, like $C([0,1])$ and $\Bbb R^\omega$, so it's not coupled to dimension. In fact a completely metrisable such space cannot be countable dimensional, because Baire fails almost always in such spaces.

Comment: I already proved my statement, the qiestion was about metrisability of weak topology on $X$ generated by $Y$, i didn't say that metrizability of space is equavalent to countability of space

Comment: @NeoFanatic the metrisabity is linked to the countable subfamily of seminorms.

Comment: Exactly, and in case of dual pair $(X,Y)$ the weak topology on $X$ is metrizable iff $dim \; Y$ at most countable in classical sence how allesandro wrote.